# How to remove the top safe area in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am developing a screen using SwiftUI, want to display my view in the top safe area of the screen, is there any method to achieve this in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 35):

Use this modifier:

```
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
```

If you want to ignore all the safe area insets you can pass `.all`

Comment: . edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top) is much better in this case

Comment: To which view should I apply this on the watch?

Answer (score 16):

#### SwiftUI 2.0

You can use this modifier to pass in the region and the edges you need to ignore

```
.ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: .top)
```

<sub>**Note:** Both parameters are optional</sub>

This modifier is very useful when you need to react to the keyboard as the region. The old modifier is not deprecated yet and you can still use it as the primary method:

---

#### SwiftUI 1.0

Use this modifier if need to support iOS 13

```
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
```

#### Note:

You can pass `.all` for both modifiers if you wish to ignore all edges.

Answer (score 2):

By default SwiftUI views will mostly stay inside the safe area. It will go to the bottom of the screen, but it won’t go near any notch at the top of the device. If you want your view to be truly full screen, then you should use the **`edgesIgnoringSafeArea()`** modifier.

```
struct MyView : View {

    var body: some View {
         Text("Welcome to Swift UI")
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
     }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this and it does get rid of the safe area, but touches in the space where the safe areas was are ignored. Also the NavigationBarTitle doesn't move. What is needed is a means to simply turn off the safe area.

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
 This extension is needed because of deprecating edgesignoringsafearea for iOS 13.0–15.2
 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu/edgesignoringsafearea(_:)
 */
public extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func expandViewOutOfSafeArea(_ edges: Edge.Set = .all) -> some View {
        if #available(iOS 14, *) {
            self.ignoresSafeArea(edges: edges)
        } else {
            self.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(edges) // deprecated for iOS 13.0–15.2, look upper
        }
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
MyView()
   .expandViewOutOfSafeArea()
```